# Why is my code is not working? This method must return a result of type int

Tags: java

**Im trying to code a tic tac toe game using the minimax algorithm. but the method failing, it always says "This method must return a result of type int"**

the method is allways is going to return a result of type int

```java
 static int minimax(String[][] board, int depth, boolean maxPlayer) 
    {
      if (depth == 0 || gameOver(board) == true)
      {
        return gameEvaluation(board);
      }
      if (maxPlayer == true)
      {
        int maxEval = -100; 
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
          for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
          {
            if (board[x][y].equals(" "))
            {          
              board[x][y] = "x";
              int eval = minimax(board, (depth - 1), false); 
              maxEval = Math.max(maxEval, eval); 
              board[x][y] = " "; 
              return maxEval; 
            }
           
          }
        }
      }
      else
      {
        int minEval = 100; 
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
          for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
          {
            if (board[x][y].equals(" "))
            {
              String[][] tempBoard = board; 
              tempBoard[x][y] = "o";
              int eval = minimax(tempBoard, (depth - 1), true); 
              minEval = Math.max(minEval, eval); 
              return minEval; 
            }
          
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: What does this return `return gameEvaluation(board);` ?

Comment: It does not define what should be returned if there is no element in the board equal to " ". Every possible execution path (even if you are never calling your function which will go those paths) has to end in a return statement.

Comment: If `gameEvaluation` returns `int` maybe it will return `int` every time. But you must write `return` on every possible execution path (compiler doesn't know if `for` will always hit `return`) so just store evaluation in local variable and return it on the end of function.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to break up your logic in smaller methods.  For started, everything in your second if{} should go into one method and everything your else{} should go in another method. Then you can unit test each one independently for debugging.
2. if a method has a return value, ALWAYS have the last line in that method to either return a known value or throw an exception.  This is your problem. Whatever use case you have isn't hitting your other return statements so the method reaches the end with no return and throws the exception.